# multiple join clause ended with a group join LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by

I working on an app with a SQLite database, now I want to select information from multiple tables using linq, here it is what I did:

```
from c in dataContext.Convention
join e in dataContext.Engineer on c.Engineer equals e.Code
join o in dataContext.Owner on c.Owner equals o.Code
join t in dataContext.ProjectType on c.ProjectType equals t.Id
join cs in dataContext.ConventionState on c.State equals cs.Id
join sc in dataContext.SiteControl on c.Code equals sc.CodeCv
join pc in dataContext.PlanControl on c.Code equals pc.CodeCv
join scs in dataContext.SiteState on sc.State equals scs.Id
join pcs in dataContext.PlanState on pc.State equals pcs.Id
join rcs in dataContext.ReceptionState on sc.Reception equals rcs.Id
join b in dataContext.Bill on c.Code equals b.CodeCv
where cs.Abr == "EC"
group new { c, e, o, t, scs, pcs, rcs, b } by new
{ c.Code, c.NumSeq, c.Year, c.TotalAmount, c.Title, e.LastName, e.FirstName, o.Name,
tprjt = t.Abr,
scState = scs.Abr,
pcState = pcs.Abr,
rcState = rcs.Abr
} into cvgrp
select new
{
     Code = cvgrp.Key.Code,
     N_Seq = cvgrp.Key.NumSeq,
     Exercice = cvgrp.Key.Year,
     Intitulé = cvgrp.Key.Title,
     Ingenieur = cvgrp.Key.LastName + " " + cvgrp.Key.FirstName,
     MaitreOuvrage = cvgrp.Key.Name,
     TypeProjet = cvgrp.Key.tprjt,
     CtrlPlan = cvgrp.Key.pcState,
     CtrlChantier = cvgrp.Key.scState,
     Reception = cvgrp.Key.rcState,
     Montant = cvgrp.Key.TotalAmount,
     MontantFacturé = cvgrp.Sum(x => x.b.Amount),
     MontantRestant = cvgrp.Key.TotalAmount - cvgrp.Sum(x => x.b.Amount),
     MontantCréance = cvgrp.Sum(x => x.b.IsPaid == "False" ? x.b.Amount : 0.0 )
 }
```

It seems working but I really don't understand clearly what I did especially in the group by clause. If I add an into clause after the joins before the group by the identifier will work as a table with all the tables joined ?.
I need some explanation to understand linq more.
Thank you in advance.

[image: database schema]